# WebSocket service always closes the connection after receiving a message from the client when connecting through Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I deployed a WebSocket service on Azure Kubernetes. It's worked fine if connect to the service directly, but when I try to connect my service through API Management. It always closes the connection after receiving a message from the client.

***Service code***

```
 from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Header, Response
 from fastapi import WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect, Query
 from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
    
 from pathlib import Path
    
 import os
 import time
 import websockets
 import logging
    
 from custom_logging import CustomizeLogger
    
 app = FastAPI()
 app.add_middleware(
     CORSMiddleware,
     allow_origins=["*"],
     allow_credentials=True,
     allow_methods=["*"],
     allow_headers=["*"],
 )
    
 # logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 config_path=Path(__file__).with_name("log_config.json")
 logger = CustomizeLogger.make_logger(config_path)
    
 @app.websocket("/ws")
 async def websoc(websocket: WebSocket):
     await websocket.accept()
     try:
         while True:
             msg = await websocket.receive_text()
             logger.info('recieve:'+ msg)
    
             await websocket.send_text(msg)
            
     except Exception as e:
         logger.info(e)
```

***Client Code***

```
 import websockets
 import asyncio
 import time
    
 async def send_receive():
     async with websockets.connect(
         'wss://xxxx.azure-api.net/testwebsocket?subscription-key=xxx', 
                                   ping_interval=5,
                                   ping_timeout=20) as websocket:
         for i in range(10):
             await websocket.send(str(i))
             await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
             msg = await websocket.recv()
             print(msg)
            
 asyncio.run(send_receive())
```

Result from my custom log on service when call through API management
[image]

Result from my custom log on service when call it directly
[image]

---

Network trace from backend.

Red is API management.
Blue is backend.
[image]

Network trace from my local machine.

Red is API management.
Green is local machine.

[image]

---

Logs from APIM
[image]
[image]

Comment: Collect Network traces and see who closes the connection, you may need to collect traces from your backend as well.

Comment: I have no idea what I need to check up on network trace, but it seems to be APIM closes the connection. Please see my edited post. @Mohamad

Comment: @ThananchaiKongthaworn Did you try looking at apim gateway logs using azure monitor? What the error reason for disconnection there?

Comment: I already added logs to my post, there is response code 0, Is this error? @JJ.

Comment: I would suggest to open a support ticket as it seems to be difficult to troubleshoot this here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APIM does not support custom `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions`. Your client websocket library is likely sending some. You can add a set `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header to be empty in api policy and confirm. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader

Comment: There is a fix coming in APIM for this